# The Code in JavaScript file is not being appended to html.

Tags: javascript, html

This is the html code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>Advanced JavaScript Project. </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="learning.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="theBody">
 <h3>Matching Game</h3>
 <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left.</p>
 <div id="leftSide">
  <h3>Left Div</h3>
 </div>

 <div id="rightSide">
  <h3>Right Div</h3>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is the JavaScript Code.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.innerText = i;
   body.appendChild(div);
}
```

I'm not understanding as to why this code is not working as expected. 
I want to add 10 divs to html.

Comment: `body[0].appendChild(div);`

Comment: You could just use `document.body.appendChild(div);`

Comment: I found the answer. Just add the script tag before the end of the body.